# Problem with implementing Comparable interface

Tags: java, interface, comparable

I have below codes that I implement form chapter 9 in book "Java for Everyone":

```
package Inheritance;

import java.util.Scanner;

interface Comparable{
    int compareTo(Object otherObject);
}

interface Measurable{
    double getMeasure();
}


public class BankAccount implements Comparable, Measurable {
    private double balance;
    private int counter;
    public String account;

    public BankAccount(){
        balance = 0;
        counter = 0;
        account = "";
    }

    public void SetAccount(String accountNumber, double amount){
        account = accountNumber;
        balance = amount;
    }

    public void Deposit(double amount){
        balance = balance + amount;
        counter = counter + 1;
        System.out.println("Account: "+ account + " has balance: " + balance);
    }

    public void Withdraw(double amount){
        balance = balance - amount;
        counter = counter + 1;
        System.out.println("Account: "+ account + " has balance: " + balance);
    }

    public double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }

    public void MonthEnd(){
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void printMenu(){
        System.out.println("Please choose your options to proceed: ");
        System.out.println("D)eposit W)ithdraw M)onth end Q)uit");
    }

    public double getMeasure(){
        return balance;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object otherObject) {
        BankAccount other = (BankAccount) otherObject;
        if (balance < other.balance) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (balance > other.balance) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Then I run it as below:

```
public class Implementation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Implement Comparable Interface example
        BankAccount[] accounts2 = new BankAccount[3];
        accounts2[0] = new BankAccount();
        accounts2[0].SetAccount("SA001", 10000);
        accounts2[1] = new BankAccount();
        accounts2[1].SetAccount("SA001", 5000);
        accounts2[2] = new BankAccount();
        accounts2[2].SetAccount("SA001", 20000);
        System.out.println(accounts2[0].compareTo(accounts2[1]));

        Arrays.sort(accounts2);
    }
}
```

However it gave me below error with my Comparable interface. I already provided the compareTo method in the BankAccount class, why does it not work?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Inheritance.BankAccount cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable (Inheritance.BankAccount is in unnamed module of loader 'app';
 java.lang.Comparable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)

```
at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)

at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1250)

at Inheritance.Implementation.main(Implementation.jav
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of:

```
interface Comparable{
    int compareTo(Object otherObject);
}
```

Since you're confusing the compiler by creating your own interface that shadows the core Java interface *of the same name*. Instead use the core Java Comparable interface.

The issue here is that the `Arrays.sort(...)` method must use the core interface and not your own. Otherwise your code *could* possibly work although would likely confuse other coders and more importantly *your future self*.

Side note, I would recommend using the generic version of the interface. I also like to *always* add the `@Override` annotation above any method that I think that I *might* be overriding so that the compiler will test this for me and warn me at compile time:

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount>, Measurable {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BankAccount other) {
        // ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make work Arrays.sort(accounts2) function working, your BankAccount class has to implement the Comaparable interface provided by jdk itself - java.lang.Comparable.
Not the one you have created.

Remove below code from your BankAccount class. This will work.

```
interface Comparable{
int compareTo(Object otherObject);
```

}